# Adding class to one element instead of all of them, example inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm struggling here. I want to make an on click even that when I click on a navigation, it opens nested list and add class to parent list.
That part almost works, problem is that it adds that class to all elements from parent list.

```
       <ul>
        <li><div><p class="hidden">Test 1</p>
            <ul class="shown">
                <li>
                   <a href="#"><p>Inner 1</p></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><div><p  class="hidden">Test 2</p>
            <ul class="shown">
                <li>
                   <a href="#"><p>Inner 2</p></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
```

jque

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('.shown').hide();
$('.hidden').click(function () {
    var $answer = $(this).next('.shown');
    if ($answer.is(':hidden')) {
        $answer.show();
                     $('.hidden').addClass('color1');
    } else {
        $answer.hide();
        $('.hidden').removeClass('color1');
    }
});

    });
```

css

```
.color1{
   background:red;
}
```

jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Lc5n8k81/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here while adding and removing color1 class change $('.hidden') to $(this).. as $('.hidden') will add class to all element with .hidden class

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6moznpbr/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.shown').hide();
    $('.hidden').click(function () {
        var $answer = $(this).next('.shown');
        if ($answer.is(':hidden')) {
            $answer.show();
                         $(this).addClass('color1');
        } else {
            $answer.hide();
            $(this).removeClass('color1');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your click handler, you want to refer to `$(this)` not `$('.hidden')` - the latter means *all* elements with class `hidden`:

```
$('.hidden').click(function () {
    var $answer = $(this).next('.shown');
    if ($answer.is(':hidden')) {
        $answer.show();
        $(this).addClass('color1');
    } else {
        $answer.hide();
        $(this).removeClass('color1');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lc5n8k81/2/